# Sort entities based on fetched property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my application (written in Swift) I use a model for Core Data with two configurations, each of these uses different save path (one is read-only in the application bundle and another is in the Documents folder). I set in one of two configurations an entity "Domanda" with the following attributes:
[image: Domanda Entity]
In the other configuration I set an entity "StatDomanda" with the following attributes:
[image: StatDomanda Entity]
"StatDomanda" is used for user data, while "Domanda" is used as preloaded source. I  know that I can't set up a relationship between the two entities (two configurations), but I would order the "Domanda" entity based on the "corrette" attribute of the "StatDomanda" entity where StatDomanda.numero == Domanda.numero and StatDomanda .argomento == Domanda.argomento.nomeArgomento.
Not all "Domanda" objects have corresponding "StatDomanda" objects.
I set a fetched property (called "statistiche") in the "Domanda" entity with this predicate

> $FETCH_SOURCE.numero = numero AND
>   $FETCH_SOURCE.argomento.nomeArgomento = argomento

but I do not understand how to use it to order the objects.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't know if is the best way but it works!
In my core data manager class (ModelManager) I have this function used to fetch all the "Domanda" entities:

```
func getAllQuestions() -> [Domanda] {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Domanda")
        let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Domanda]
        return fetchResults!
    }
```

In my ViewController I use this code to obtain the sorted array of "Domanda" entities based on attribute "corrette" of "statistiche" fetched property:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var arrayDomande  = ModelManager.instance.getAllQuestions()
    var sortedArrayDomande = self.sortArray(arrayToSort: arrayDomande)
}

func sortArray(arrayToSort sarray: Array<Domanda>) -> Array<Domanda> {

        // 1 - Filter the array to find only questions that have stats
        var onlyAnswered = sarray.filter({($0.valueForKey("statistiche") as [Domanda]).count == 1})

        // 2 - Sort the array based on fetched property
        var sortedArrayDomande = sorted(onlyAnswered, {
            let first = ($0.valueForKey("statistiche") as [StatDomanda])[0]
            let firstC = first.corrette.integerValue

            let second = ($1.valueForKey("statistiche") as [StatDomanda])[0]
            let secondC = second.corrette.integerValue

            return firstC > secondC
        })

        return sortedArrayDomande
    }
```

or even in condensed form:

```
// 2 - Sort the array based on fetched property
var sortedArrayDomande = sorted(onlyAnswered, {($0.valueForKey("statistiche") as [StatDomanda])[0].corrette.integerValue > ($1.valueForKey("statistiche") as [StatDomanda])[0].corrette.integerValue})
```

Goodbye guys, see you next time!